# Django Admin | Group data in object list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I just got the requirement to show data on Django admin panel in a certain way.
Actually I have log table in which I have userid and action it took.

```
class AuditTrail(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  userid = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, db_column='UserId')
  action = models.CharField(max_length=200L, db_column='Action')
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_column='Timestamp', blank=True)
```

When I add it on the admin panel it just give me all the entries in AuditTrail table.
I have created filters on timestamp, search on userid and default ordering. But what actually is needed is on the main page where all the entries are shown I need to group rows on userid. and on clicking userid I need to implement expand/collapse logic.

In short on the main page of the model I get list of all users and I can collapse and expand all the rows for that user. Can I achieve this somehow in django admin panel. Does django give the functionality of grouping model objects on some field?
Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
If it is not achievable in Django? What i have done now is i have created a link for each user's audit trail and i created a custom field and added in User's table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [customise the default template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) and add [asset definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions).

For grouping you might need [regroup builtin tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

Comment: Yeah, I just did this. Not a small job, and plenty of caveats. Selecting rows to perform admin actions breaks, and exporting to CSV.